# String to XML, The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I know same sort of questions have already been answered but mine is bit different in nature, so i am trying to parse an XML-String to write it back to an already created xml file, the error i am getting is that

> The markup in the document following the root element must be
>   well-formed.

Actually i know the error and the thing causing is that i don't have any root element in my generated-xml-string because i already have my root element in the xml i am just trying to append new xml tags to an already created file.

my xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<perk-users>
<user pin="73000001">
  <property email="example@example.com"/>
  <property username="73000001abcdef"/>
  <property ecoid="AXHN6yllzrxGmJduzLzsiOk%3D"/>
</user>
<user pin="73000002">
  <property email="example@example.com"/>
  <property username="73000002abcdef"/>
  <property ecoid="AXHN6yllzrxGmJduzLzsiOk%3D"/>
</user>
</perk-users>
```

And the xml string i have is:

```
<user id="73000009">
  <property email="example@example.com"/>
  <property username="73000009abcdef"/>
  <property ecoid="AXHN6yllzrxGmJduzLzsiOk%3D"/>
</user>
<user id="73000004">
  <property email="example@example.com"/>
  <property username="73000004abcdef"/>
  <property ecoid="AXHN6yllzrxGmJduzLzsiOk%3D"/>
</user>
```

The code is:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = loadDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

            Document doc2 = dBuilder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(generatedXML.getBytes()));

            Node node = doc.importNode(doc2.getDocumentElement(), true);
            rootElement.appendChild(node);
            writeToXML(doc);
```

So it basically crashes at dbuilder.parse() as i know there is no root element in my generatedXML, so please suggest me a way where i could write/append to `<perk-users>` this same xml string.

Comment: What is the type of `generatedXML`?

Comment: `String` , i am actually appending xml from a loop to this variable and then trying to eventually dump this string into xml doc.

Comment: So before invoquing `getBytes()`, perhaps you can simply use something like `("<perk-users>" + generatedXML + "</perk-users>").getBytes()`. Then you should loop on all the childNodes.

Comment: thanks alot but i have already figured it out the same way u mentioned. so we think alike :) actually i didn't wanted to append the root el in my xml-string but now didn't see any other way so i just appened the root el and then iterated through its child nodes and made it to work.. thnx for the help anyway.

Comment: I think there's no other way than the one you described. Go ahead :)

Comment: Post the answer for the benefit of future readers?